# ITMS installer authentication cookie

Tags: ios, authentication, itunes, ota

We are deploying iOS apps over the air (OTA) to our enterprise to employees and we are controlling who can access the download site via username/password login page authenticates the user and authorizes them based on AD group membership. This authentication process creates a cookie on the browser. 
The problem is, the ITMS installer ("itms-Services://") does not get the authentication cookie, so that we are getting an error “cannot connect to server”

The error log in the device is

Jun 28 12:22:32 iPhone itunesstored[105] : Could not load download manifest with underlying error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we solved this issue. The ipa file should be directly accessed. So the authentication for that file is bypassed.